# combine two 2-dimensional arrays to produce a 3-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r

Consider the arrays `x` and `y`

```
x <- structure(1:4, .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(A = c("a", 
"b"), B = c("c", "d")), .Names = c("A", "B")))
y <- structure(5:8, .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(A = c("a", 
"b"), B = c("c", "d")), .Names = c("A", "B")))
> x
   B
A   c d
  a 1 3
  b 2 4
> y
   B
A   c d
  a 5 7
  b 6 8
```

How do you combine them to produce `z`:

```
> z
, , C = e

   B
A   c d
  a 1 3
  b 2 4

, , C = f

   B
A   c d
  a 5 7
  b 6 8
```

It looks like a fairly common operation but I haven't found a function that
does this.

Comment: `array(c(x, y), c(2, dim(x)), dimnames(x))` maybe?

Comment: Use the *abind* package.

Comment: Or use any image-related package, as they allow you to build "layers" in 3D quite easily.  .. or as the simplest but perhaps most clumsy,  `z <-array(dim=c(2,2,2)); z[,,1]<-x; z[,,2]<-y`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think the second argument should be `c(dim(x), 2)`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I messed up the order. The question is - does this solve your problem or you have a more complicated case in real life?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes it does, except for the dimension names, but it isn't a big deal.

Comment: As it turns out `simplify2array(list(e=x, f=y))` also does the job.